# Office 365 REST API - Outlook User Photo

Tags: c#, rest, azure, office365, office365api

I'm attempting to retrieve other users' outlook photos using the Office 365 REST API (Preview). The documentation is here on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/photo-rest-operations.

I'm able to successfully retrieve my own photo using an access token by making the following rest call:

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/me/userphoto/$value
```

However, when attempting to retrieve the photos of other people in my organization by using this REST call:

```
GET https://outlook.office365.com/api/beta/Users('{user_id}')/userphotos('{size}')/$value
```

I get the following error:

```
{
     "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
     }
}
```

This error isn't listed anywhere in the documentation as far as I can tell. I suspect this has something to do with the permissions in Azure but that's only a guess. Maybe it isn't supported in the preview API? Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nkorai, you are right, the current permission set does not allow you to see others photo. We are adding a new oauth permission to the exchange online application endpoint which will allow you to do this. We are in the process of getting this permission enabled. Hopefully in a few weeks.